# Запрет процессу просматривать запущенные процессы на компьютере

Tags: c++

Всех приветствую.

Есть 2 программы.

Если запустить первую программу - то вторая видит, что запущена первая и попросту не запускается (видимо, просматривает текущий список запущенных процессов и не открывается).

Можно ли как-то ограничить этой "второй" программе просмотр списка запущенных процессов? Чтобы при открытии первой вторая запускалась без проблем?

И ещё: переименовать программу не вариант, так как при запуске у первой программы должно быть свое стандартное название.

Что пробовал:

менял название окна (HWND)
пробовал менять название процесса после его запуска. Не удачно, так как вторая все равно как-то его видит.

Comment: Предполагаю что внутри программы у вас действие которое разрешено запускать в единственном экземпляре в ос (например одновременно слушать 2 одинаковых порта или что-то в этом духе) в пользовательском пространстве, один процесс ничего про другой не знает, если их не связывать специально.

Comment: @noname2019, нет, эта программа не слушает порты. Она вообще ничего не слушает. Это что-то обычного hello world'а

Comment: @AlexF, там просто проверяется список запущенных процессов и если есть конкретный процесс - она не запускается. Как я это выяснил? Я переименовал исполняемый файл первой и вторая программа запустилась. Но мне нужно сделать так, чтобы название первой программы не изменялось при запуске.